# How to use segments in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

In Google Analytics, we are able to create segments like below:

[image]

From the [Google Analytics API explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), we can pull the segment information be it by segment id or by its code:

[image]

I would assume we can just cut and paste that code into the google analytics core reporting v3 reference code like we do with all the other parameters:

[image]

When I run the code however, I get this error:

```
Arg, there was an API error : 400 : Invalid value 'users::condition::dateOfSession==2015-04-30;ga:sessionCount==1;condition::ga:campaign=@33100;sessions::condition::ga:userType=@Returning Visitor' 
for segment parameter.
```

I am not sure what could be wrong. When I use the segment id instead in my code for the segment parameter(segment ='gaid::xxxxxxx'), i get this error:

```
Arg, there was an API error : 400 : Segment XXXXXXXXXXX is not supported in the API.
```

Not sure how I should structure the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after tweaking with the segment code and reading more about segments in the [segments dev guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dateOfSession-example).

I was having issues with the dateOfsession parameter where i should have used '<>' instead of '=' for the date. So this is what i should have done:
`dateOfsession<>2015-04-30_2015-04-30` Somehow using '==' doesn't work.

The dateOfsession is a new parameter in the GA API and hence have little examples and documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you send to the segment, actually anything you send to any of the parameter to the reporting API must be URL encoded.

```
users::condition::dateOfSession==2015-04-30;ga:sessionCount==1;condition::ga:campaign=@33100;sessions::condition::ga:userType=@Returning Visitor
```

becomes

```
users%3A%3Acondition%3A%3AdateOfSession%3D%3D2015-04-30%3Bga%3AsessionCount%3D%3D1%3Bcondition%3A%3Aga%3Acampaign%3D%4033100%3Bsessions%3A%3Acondition%3A%3Aga%3AuserType%3D%40Returning+Visitor
```

That should work.  the only thing I am not sure about is if the `;` needs to be encode or not.  You may need to test that. I know the `==` does.   If it doesn't work let me know and I will add a few segments and do some testing myself.

Comment: Nope that didnt work whether we encoded the ';' or not. Also, i don't think the ':' needs to be encoded because when i don't use the segments and just use `metrics='ga:users, ga:sessions'` i get my data just fine.