# How to apply segment using Google Analytics .NET client

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to apply a segment for a query through Google Analytics .NET client but I am not able to get it working. Here is what I have been trying:

```
var segments = analyticsService.Management.Segments.List().Execute();
var engagedTeamsSegment = segments.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Engaged Teams", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var thirtyDaysAgo = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
var metrics = engagedTeamsSegment.Definition.Replace(';', ',');

var gaData = analyticsService
    .Data.Ga
    .Get($"ga:{profile.Id}", today.ToString(format), thirtyDaysAgo.ToString(format), metrics)
    .Execute();
```

It's getting me the below error

> An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in
>   Google.Apis.dll
>
> Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Invalid value
>   'users::condition::ga:dimension2!=0,ga:sessionCount>=2,ga:daysSinceLastSession<=14'.
>   Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+' [400]
>
> Errors [
>
> Message[Invalid value
>   'users::condition::ga:dimension2!=0,ga:sessionCount>=2,ga:daysSinceLastSession<=14'.
>   Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+']
>   Location[metrics - parameter] Reason[invalidParameter] Domain[global]
>
> ]

I am probably doing something wrong but not sure what. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if your request works in https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/ using your parameters? Just to make sure that you are doing the right call to Analytics backend.

Comment: @peleyal will try. Amy I doing the right thing by passing `engagedTeamsSegment.Definition.Replace(';', ',')` as metrics parameter above? It seems that could be the place where I do it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the API, I'll wait for someone that is more familiar with Analytics to answer here. It's not me... sorry.

Comment: @peleyal solved, look at the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203594/how-to-use-segments-in-google-analytics-api). There was a `Segment` parameter on the request. Below code did the trick:

```
var segments = analyticsService.Management.Segments.List().Execute();
var engagedTeamsSegment = segments.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Engaged Teams", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var thirtyDaysAgo = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

var gaDataRequest = analyticsService
    .Data.Ga
    .Get($"ga:{profile.Id}", thirtyDaysAgo.ToString(format), today.ToString(format), "ga:users");

gaDataRequest.Segment = engagedTeamsSegment.Definition;

var gaData = gaDataRequest.Execute();
```